finding the convergence rate and convergence constant for an iterative method.
in order to find a non linear equation $F(x)=0$ the following method is used:
$$x_{n+1}=x_n - \frac{(F(x_n))^2}{F(x_n+F(x_n))-F(x_n)}$$
we will mark by $s$ the solution $F(s)=0$, assuming that the method converges from a suitable initial value, what is the order of convergence $\alpha$ and the constant of convergence $A$?
I already know that $\alpha = 2$ and $A=\frac{1}{2}\left|\frac{F''(x)(F'(s)+1)}{F'(s)}\right|$ but cant understant how to approach this.
already tried defining a function $g(x)$ that equals to the right side of the equation and then maybe take the derivative until i will get a non zero in $s$ but it doesnt look good at all, and then i tried with expanding taylor series but then again i didnt get much further. thanks.

You might try to search with the name of the method, "Steffensen's method", quite related to Aitken's delta-squared process. proposed search
